# Javascript MouseEvent Parameter

Tags: javascript

```html
var test = document.getElementById("test");
test.onclick = function(ev) {
    console.log(ev);
}
```

How Javascript Engine know that ev is an EventMouse?
Can I create a function and assign parameters like this?

Comment: 1. If you want to see how look at the engine code that your browser is using. 2. Yes

Comment: see this https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp  and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event

Answer (score 1):

you are registering to an event, the browser pass a certain object when it triggers that event.  you can do it with custom events yourself:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Answer (score 0):

There are predefined event handler methods which accept `event` as a parameter to provide additional control on handling that event. You can't just create any function and expect event object to be available there. All the system event handler functions like `onPress, onMouseMove, onKeyDown`, etc. can accept optional argument of `event`